# Rubyist way to test for a hash key in an array

Tags: json, ruby

I am parsing some JSON which has been converted to Ruby data structures. I have records that look either like this:

`"uros"=>[{"ure"=>"zip*less", "prs"=>[{"mw"=>"ˈzip-ləs", "sound"=>{"audio"=>"ziples01", "ref"=>"c", "stat"=>"1"}}]`

or like this:

`"uros"=>[{"ure"=>"gas chromatographic", "fl"=>"adjective"}]`

I want to pull out the hash value for the key `audio` when it appears.

What is the clean way to test for the presence of said key in Ruby? Here are my attempts thus far. The variable `entry` represents the enclosing data structure:

```
if entry["uros"] != nil # Nope              
#if entry["uros"]["prs"] != nil  # Nope 
#if not entry["uros"]["prs"]["sound"]["audio"].first.instance_of? nil  # Nope 
#if ! entry["uros"]["prs"].instance_of? nil  # Nope 

    puts entry["uros"].first["prs"].first["sound"]["audio"]

end
```

The error message I get is either:

```
undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

or conversely:

```
 undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Hash has a [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) for checking presence of a key-value pair

```
if entry.key?('uros')
```

But problem with your code is you don't check for existence of the nested keys. You check for "uros", but then "prs" might not exist.

Here's a better version that allows nils at every step

```
audio = entry.dig('uros', 0, 'prs', 0, 'sound', 'audio')
```

Comment: @Schwern yep, in ruby 2.3+

Comment: @Schwern, ...and [OpenStruct#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-dig), with all three doing handoffs to each other.

Comment: Beware of using `dig` when the hash structure is known and the nested keys should all be present, for the simple reason that it's preferable to have an exception raised when a hash does not have a key that should be present than for `dig` to quietly return `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `[]` is to `fetch` as `dig` is to...? Is there an equivalent of `dig` which throws a KeyError?

Comment: @Schwern, not that I know of but presumably it would be a replacement for `h[key1][key2][key3]`, which itself it pretty straightforward.

Comment: @CarySwoveland How about `audio = [entry, 'uros', 0, 'prs', 0, 'sound', 'audio'].reduce(:fetch)`
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator) to search around the the data structure without getting a bunch of NoMethodErrors. The safe navigation operator will call the method, or return `nil` if called on `nil`.

```
audio = entry["uros"]
  &.first
  &.[]("prs")
  &.first
  &.dig("sound", "audio")
```

This might look funny, but remember that [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) is just another method. If any part of that method chain returns `nil`, the whole thing will return `nil`.

`entry["uros"]&.first` is roughly equivalent to...

```
entry["uros"].first if entry["uros"] != nil
```